Не могу сделать makemigrations и запустить проект
<class 'authre.admin.CustomUserAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'is_active', which does not refer to a Field.
authre/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    expires_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        # Проверяем, истек ли срок действия пользователя
        if self.expires_at and self.expires_at < timezone.now():
            return False
        return True  # Или вернуть значение от super(), если вы хотите сохранить логику




authre/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'expires_at', 'is_active')
    list_filter = ('is_active',)  # Здесь 'is_active' - это поле, унаследованное от AbstractUser.


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)




про отображения properties в админке писали, что нужно это property еще прописать в readonly_fields в админ-модели. типа readonly_fields= ('is_active',).

Мне нужно это поле чтобы прописывать значение в админке, а не просто читать(

И все же ошибка не исчезла

Чтобы «прописывать значение», нужно, очевидно, хотя бы реализовать возможность записи в этом property, а вы его не реализовали

Ну и «поле, унаследованное от AbstractUser» — конечно же нет, потому что вы в CustomUser заменили это поле на свой property, который недоступен для записи
